# How to enable HTTPS for Zabbix

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, https, zabbix

How to configure make Zabbix accessible using HTTPS? - Ubuntu Apache!

Currently Zabbix is accessible on Intranet via http://192.160.1.1/zabbix where I would like to setup to access it like https://192.160.1.1/zabbix

Thanks

Comment: Well, just enable https then in the apache https server. You will have to use a "self signed certificate", since it is impossible to get a signed one for an internal system. So the users will have to accept that certificate once. But apart from that I do not see any issues here.

Comment: You are right! I just enabled HTTPS by entering the below commands! 
a2enmod ssl
a2ensite default-ssl
service apache2 restart

It worked!

Comment: @rijAthmohAmmednr I tried it but somehow it fails. Could you please paste the section of your apache conf file? It will be very helpfull for me to figure out the cause of failure.

Comment: @Yogesh I only ran above mentioned 2 commands, once that is done I was able to connect using https. http://askubuntu.com/questions/709594/how-disable-and-enable-ssl-in-apache-without-a-command

Comment: @rijAthmohAmmednr thanks for the link..will try it..

Comment: @rijAthmohAmmednr thanks for commenting with your solution.  You should  consider adding it as an answer to your own question (which is not bad etiquette).  It will help more people and you may get upvotes for it.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to arrange SSL on my Zabbix site by having a named vhost (mytest.site.com) with any docroot (/var/www/mytest.site.com/public_html). Zabbix hooks into any /zabbix url, so it doesn't really matter which one. It is important that you have a valid DNS resolving to your vhost. Then use Letsencrypt to create a SSL certificate for that vhost and have it forward traffic to port 80 to port 443 (see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04 for installation details).